# ggplot gradient color for geom_line

Tags: r, ggplot2

take the following data and graph

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3),
                 cond = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2),
                 Time = c(1,2,1,2,1,2),
                 State  = c("Empty", "Empty", "Empty", "Full", "Full", "Empty"),
                 eye = c(2, -3, -2, 1, 0, -2),
                 combination = c(1, 1,2, 2, 3, 3))
```

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = Time, y = eye)) +
  geom_point(aes(shape=State), size = 3.5) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(13,15)) +  
  geom_line(aes(group=ID, color = Time), size = 5) +
    
  theme(legend.title=element_blank(),
        axis.title.x=element_text(size = 12),
        axis.title.y=element_text(size = 12),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 15),
        axis.text.x= element_text(color = "black"),
        axis.text.y= element_text(color = "black"),
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
        plot.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"))
```

How do I make the lines a gradient color? The legend displays a gradient color-scheme, but as illustrated the lines don't seem to follow it accurately.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe you can vary aesthetics like color within a single instance of a geom in ggplot2 without extra interpolation steps. `ggforce::geom_link2` would be a good drop-in replacement to accomplish this:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = Time, y = eye)) +
  ggforce::geom_link2(aes(group=ID, color = Time), size = 5, n = 500, lineend = "round") +
  geom_point(aes(shape=State), size = 3.5) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(13,15)) + ....
```

[image]

Comment: This solved the asked question perfectly, thanks! Would you also know if it is possible to get different colors for the different lines? Such that, for instance, one line is blue-yellow, another is yellow-red and a third is green-purple?

Comment: I don't know a simple way to do that, but a quick hack could be to use `color = Time + ID)` and a line like `scale_color_distiller(palette = "Set1")`. This would give you different color ranges for each line. Alternately you might assign color to ID and alpha to time to get a graduated version of each color.

Comment: Assigning color to ID and alpha to Time is a good solution, but I am having problems with how the graduation works - unlike the working example above where the graduation of color grows evenly across the line, when I set Alpha = Time the alpha does not change it a neat graduated way, it almost instantly becomes alpha 1 right at the beginning/end of the line. Do you know a fix for this?

Comment: It looks like alpha is going to be hard to control with ggforce::geom_link2, since it relies on overlapping segments, and I'm also struggling with changing the alpha transition curve, despite trying the advice here: http://sape.inf.usi.ch/quick-reference/ggplot2/alpha